# Is it possible to use Microsoft Data Protection Manager without clients being registered in DNS?

Tags: backup, scdpm

TL;DR -- Is there any way to get Microsoft DPM 2012 R2 back up domain clients that don't exist in DNS?

We've got a (maybe) unique setup where our domain clients pull IPs from a DHCP that assigns them from a pool that resolves to n-{x}-{y}.dhcp.domain.local and uses domain.local's DNS.  We run a domain that looks like a child domain, but lives in a different forest, called our.domain.local.  Our domain clients are a part of our.domain.local, but since they don't register in our.domain.local's DNS, Data Protection Manager can't see them.  We usually just register IPs for our servers in our DNS, for which DPM works very nicely.

I'm pretty sure the answer to my question is 'No', but I'm hoping that maybe there's some trick or configuration that would make it possible.